# How to run multiple spring boot webapps with embedded tomcat and different domain names

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, web-applications

I know that when hosting a Spring Boot webapp with embedded Tomcat, you simply package it as a .jar file, upload to server and run it. And then your domain, pointing at the server IP, will direct HTTP to that webapp through port 80.

But what do I do, if I want to host two (or more) Spring Boot webapps with embedded Tomcat, that has different domain names.
Lets say: "www.foo.com" and "www.bar.com" - how do I control that requests to "www.foo.com" is handled by webapp1 while all requests to "www.bar.com" is handled by webapp2?

Comment: You probably need something called Gateway on the IP and the port 80 (443). For example, https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/. Each .jar needs on the same IP a different [port](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port).